# How fix my custom function composer class?

Tags: c++

I want to write a class that will work with function compositions.

But for some reason, it doesn’t work for me as I expect.

I tried to implement using unary_function everything worked. But I don’t understand how to implement inheriting from binary_function

```
#pragma once

template<class F1, class F2, class R>
class Composer : public binary_function<F1, F2, R> {
 public: 
    Composer(F1& f1, F2& f2) 
        : f1_(f1), f2_(f2) {}

    R operator() (R v) {
        return f1_(f2_(v));
    }

 private:
    F1 f1_;
    F2 f2_;
};

// helper function 
template<class F1, class F2, class R>
inline Composer<F1, F2, R> Compose(F1& f1, F2& f2) {
    return Composer<F1, F2, R>(f1, f2);
}
```

Example use in code:

```
struct Square : public unary_function<int, int> {
    int operator()(int i) const { return i * i; }
};

struct Print : public unary_function<int, int> {
    int operator()(int a) const { cout << a << "\t"; return 0; }
};

int main() {
    vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    for_each(vi.begin(), vi.end(),
    Composer<Print, Square, int>(Print(), Square()) # error
    );

    remove_copy_if(vi.begin(), vi.end(),
                          back_inserter(vi_new),
                             Compose(bind2nd(greater<int>(), 10), Square()) #error
    );
}
```

ERRORS: 
error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Composer'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2783: 'Composer Compose(F1 &,F2 &)': could not deduce template argument for 'R'
error C2672: 'remove_copy_if': no matching overloaded function found
...

Comment: a binary function takes two arguments, not one. Please include the errors in the question

Comment: why do you think you need to inherit from `unary_function` / `binary_function` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818, you think i dont need?

Comment: they are deprecated and removed in c++17, and I don't understand what they are good for.